# swift for loop understanding

Tags: swift, for-loop

I need to ask about the for loop. I have basic understanding for loop.
i'm trying to understand it as much as i can. 
example here:

How to access/add that **self.imageList to self.photo array**? 
i've tried with **self.photo.image = self.imageList[0]** and so on.

it doens't look good and if a photo is missing i will get index error. 
i have also tried putting another for loop inside the **for pic in parseProfilePic {** the loop somehow repeats 20 times and end up using the last looped image. :( i want to end up **self.photo.image = object["photo"] self.photo2.image = object["photo2"] so on...** 
Thanks

```
var parseProfilePic = [object["photo"], object["photo2"], object["photo3"], object["photo4"]]
var photos = [self.photo, self.photo2, self.photo3, self.photo4]

for pic in parseProfilePic {
    pic?.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageFiles, error) in
        if error == nil {
            if let image = UIImage(data: imageFiles!) {
                self.imageList.append(image)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Sorry I cant work out what you are trying to achieve, do you need to append the image that results from the imageFiles object in the block of getDataInBackgroundWithblock onto ImageList or onto the parseProfilePic array? What are self.photo, self.pho2, etc. are those UIImageView outlets?

Comment: ok, i am looping through the var parseProfilePic(PFFiles) and append them on self.imageList(UIimage). so my question is how do i loop through in self.imageList so it can be displayed on self.photo.image self.photo2.image and self.photo3.image?

Answer (score 0):

So if all you need to do is append your images from imageList (asuming this is an array with a fixed length) onto your outlets, a simple switch would work.

Alternatively you can use *enumerate* to get the index *i* of the current item in the for, and use that to append to the appropriate image. Something along the lines of:

```
for (i, item) in imageList.enumerate() {
    self.photos[i].image = item
}
```

Cheers.